# Oracle 10g : CASE within select statement (ORA-00936 error)

Tags: oracle10g, ora-00936

I am executing this statement in Oracle 10g.

```
     select CASE Math WHEN BETWEEN 90 AND 100 THEN 'A'
                      WHEN BETWEEN 80 AND 90  THEN 'B'
                      WHEN BETWEEN 0  AND 80  THEN 'C'
                      ELSE 'Invalid score' END
       from score
```

But I am getting the following error

> ORA-00936: missing expression

Can somebody help on what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

In a SQL statement, the `CASE` statement would need to be something like

```
SELECT CASE WHEN math BETWEEN 90 AND 100 
            THEN 'A'
            WHEN math BETWEEN 80 AND 90
            THEN 'B'
            WHEN math BETWEEN 0 AND 80
            THEN 'C'
            ELSE 'Invalid Score'
         END
  FROM score
```

The `CASE variable WHEN` syntax is valid in PL/SQL but not in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the condition I would do this:

```
 select CASE WHEN math BETWEEN 90 AND 100 THEN 'A'
                      WHEN math BETWEEN 80 AND 90  THEN 'B'
                      WHEN math BETWEEN 0  AND 80  THEN 'C'
                      ELSE 'Invalid score' END
       from score
```

I don't think Oracle likes the BETWEEN function without a preceding variable.

Comment: No, it took the between as Justin mentioned. Thanks northpole!

Comment: yup, looks like Justin and I have the same solution. Cheers!